# chdir not working in unix under c code always failing to change directory

Tags: c, linux, ftp

I am working on an ftp server in C under unix, I am having trouble implementing the change working directory function, I already have `<unistd.h>` included what do you think the problem is?

```
static int cwd(int ctrlfd, char *cmdline) {

    printf("cmdline:%s\n", cmdline);


    char *space = strtok(cmdline, " \n");
    printf("cwd to :%s\n", cmdline);

    if (chdir(space) == 0) {
        getcwd(space, sizeof(space));
        printf("changing directory successful %s\n", space);
        return ftp_send_resp(ctrlfd, 250); 
    } else {
        printf("changing directory failed\n");
        return ftp_send_resp(ctrlfd, 550);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass an incorrect size to `getcwd`:

```
getcwd(space, sizeof(space))
```

`space` is a pointer, sizeof is not the size of the buffer, just that of the pointer.

**EDIT** from the discussion in comments, try modifying your function to use a proper buffer for reading the new current directory if successful and produce a more informative message in case of failure:

```
#include <errno.h>

static int cwd(int ctrlfd, char *cmdline) {

    printf("cmdline:%s\n", cmdline);
    char temp[200];

    /* skip initial whitespace and cut argument on whitespace if any */
    char *space = strtok(cmdline, " \n");
    printf("cwd to :%s\n", cmdline);

    if (chdir(space) == 0) {
        getcwd(temp, sizeof(temp));
        printf("changing directory successful: %s\n", temp);
        return ftp_send_resp(ctrlfd, 250); 
    } else {
        printf("changing directory to '%s' failed: %s\n",
               space, strerror(errno));
        return ftp_send_resp(ctrlfd, 550);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello thank you for your reply, getcwd() with size in this way worked well in another function

Comment: though in my code it is not even entering this zone cz chdir is always giving !=0

Comment: @Ayman: `space` might have been defined as an array in that other function.  Regarding the current issue, what does the function print for `printf("cmdline:%s\n", cmdline);`?

Comment: @Ayman You are passing an incorrect size to getcwd() in the code you posed,  it doesn't really help that it worked in another function. Your `cwd` function needs to take an extra parameter that is the length of `space` ,and you need to pass that length to `getcwd()` instead of `sizeof(space)`. `sizeof(space)` is probably 4 on your machine, and you don't want to pass 4 to getcwd()

Comment: @chqrlie this is the path sent by the filezilla or any other client I am just printing it to assure it is true

Comment: @Ayman: more precisely, can you tell us what output this `printf` call generates in a specific failure case?

Comment: @nos helo nos ading a parameter will become a very big problem for another code purposes , I tried using strlen instead but that cuased more problems , uptill now I am getting the correct path but chdir cannot change it

Comment: @chqrlie /home/ayman/Desktop
well well using copy paste I saw an additional newline to this path maybe this is the problem this is the result of the printf

Comment: @Ayman: `printf("cmdline:%s\n", cmdline);` should produce a line starting with `cmdline:`  It is important to be precise.  what do the first and second `printf` produce?

Comment: sure @chqrlie                                                            cmdline:/home/ayman/Desktop
cwd to :/home/ayman/Desktop
this is it

Comment: @Ayman: given the output, there are no separators in `cmdline`, `strtok()` returns `cmdline` and does not modify the array, `space[strlen(space) + 1] = '\0';` writes beyond the end of `cmdline`.  What is the purpose of this statement?

Comment: @chqrlie , at that point I was testing and started to add things that I supposed may cuase the problem...but yes you are right I think as long as %s in printf("cmdline:%s\n", cmdline); did its job so its not a problem !

Comment: @Ayman: you should remove the `space[strlen(space) + 1] = '\0';`, it does not serve any purpose. Also use the `temp` buffer to read the new current directory.  I shall update my answer.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for all the help , though didn't reach a correct solution but uptill now my solution is getting better I updated them

Comment: @Ayman: what is the error reported by `strerror(errno)` upon failure?